# login using PHP data object

Tags: php, passwords

When I tried to login, its always show "Incorrect Password" warning even when I have entered the right password.

Here is my login code

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['btn-login'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST)) {
        $username = $_POST['Username'];
        $password = $_POST['Password'];

        $check_stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT username,password FROM user WHERE username=?');
        $check_stmt->execute([$username]);
        $user_check = $check_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
        if($user_check > 0) {
            if(password_verify($password, $user_check['password'])) {
                $_SESSION['users'] = $username;
                header("location: home.php");
            } else {  
                Print '<script>alert("Incorrrect Password");</script>';
                Print '<script>window.location.assign("login.php");</script>';
            }
        } else {
            Print '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Username not found");</script>';
            Print '<script>window.location.assign("login.php");</script>';
        }
    } 
}
```

and this is the html form

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <label>Username : </label>
    <input type="text" name="Username" required></br>
    <label>Password : </label>
    <input type="password" name="Password" required></br>
    <input type="submit" name="btn-login" value="Login">
</form>
```

Comment: Ok and what debugging have you done?

Comment: Show us your Html-code. Did you write Password with a capital letter in the form?

Comment: I use capital letter as name in html form @WeSee

Comment: What are the values of $password and $user_check before password_verify()? please var_dump() them.

Comment: I have checked and figured that the hashed password in database has different length than actual hashed password @WeSee

Comment: What is the size of the varchar field where you store the password?